# csvhelper IsHeaderCaseSensitive Work around

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm trying to read in a csv file with a Header 'EMAIL', however, I keep getting the CsvMissingFieldException thrown "Fields 'Email' do not exist in the CSV file".

I set up the CSVreader to handle-

```
csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false;
```

but I'm still getting the same issue.   Does anyone know a work around? Or why the configuration isn't working?

In my Utilities class:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CSVreader<T>(string fileName)
        {
            using (var fileReader = File.OpenText(fileName))
            using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(fileReader))
            { 
                csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false;
                csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<OptOutClassMap>();

                while (csvReader.Read())
                {
                    var record = csvReader.GetRecord<T>();
                    yield return record;
                }
            }
        }
```

In my Class Map Class:

```
public string Email { get; set; }

public class CustomClassMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap<CustomMap>
    {
        public override void CreateMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Email);  
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the correct ClassMap. From your code above, the line:

```
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<OptOutClassMap>();
```

should be:

```
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CustomClassMap>();
```

Your code when modified works as expected.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var records = CSVreader<Record>("TextFile1.csv");            
}

public class Record
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class CustomClassMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap<Record>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Email);
    }

}

public static IEnumerable<T> CSVreader<T>(string fileName)
{
    using (var fileReader = File.OpenText(fileName))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(fileReader))
    { 
        csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false;
        csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CustomClassMap>();

        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var record = csvReader.GetRecord<T>();
            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this Mike, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you paste a snipet of your csv file?

Comment: Mike, thanks for the input, but I got this to work, apparently the root of the cause was the decryption of the file.